# BigQuery - No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_SECONDS on JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to convert a time that i have in secconds that is stored on a JSON value, and it gives me error of No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_SECONDS, or in the query results:

Invalid timestamp: '1646985600'

This is the query:

```
    SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(JSON_EXTRACT(data , '$.fechaCierre'), '$._seconds'))) AS fechaCierre
FROM db Limit 10
```

When Im querying without the DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()), like this:

```
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(JSON_EXTRACT(data , '$.fechaCierre'), '$._seconds') AS fechaCierre
FROM db Limit 10
```

Im getting correct the seconds like this: 1646985600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(JSON_EXTRACT(data , '$.fechaCierre'), '$._seconds') AS INT64))) AS fechaCierre
FROM db Limit 10
```

Comment: yep, the problem was that the result was a string and it needed to be converted first to Int64.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the result of the previous query was a string, and the TIMESTAMP_SECONDS only receive Int64.

So I change to query like this and it worked:

```
SELECT date(timestamp_seconds(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(JSON_EXTRACT(data , '$.fechaCierre'), '$._seconds') AS int64))) AS fechaCierre
FROM db Limit 10
```